# UIViewController setting new root view when click button

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have this code for a button that when clicked takes the user to the home page which is a UIViewController I have named 'HomePageViewController', I have also set the class as seen:
[class set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qTdN.png).

The button code is located in the first (initial controller) UIViewController called 'SignInViewController', when it is clicked I want the HomePageViewController to replace the SignInViewController:

```
  @IBAction func btnSignInPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // if true take to home page
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let home = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomePageViewController") as!
            HomePageViewController
            
            // replace the homepage as the root page
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
            appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = home
        }
    }
```

However, when I run this in stimulator, the button does not do anything, when I click it. Just a note, I am using a Tab Bar Controller, so I tried setting the root to the UIBarController, however this also did not work.

Comment: why you are execute this block into `DispatchQueue.main.async` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your appDelegate, add property:

```
final var window: UIWindow?
```

Call it like this

```
@IBAction func btnSignInPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // if true take to home page
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let home = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomePageViewController") as!
            HomePageViewController

        let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!
        window.rootViewController = nil
        window.rootViewController = home
        
        UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.4, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: nil, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and received an error for this line, I have commented the error I recieved: let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!! //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I thought it would be good to put the dispatch in for when I hook up the code to JSON and apply logic etc.

Comment: I forgot to add this.

In your AppDelegate, add this property:

final var window: UIWindow?

Comment: @TomoNorbert I just realised the code does not show my TabBar at the bottom?

Comment: Oh, If you want to change the viewControllers inside the UITabBarController, use the tabBarController.setViewControllers([home], animated: true) to replace viewcontrollers